# Filtering columns in dataframe that begin with a specific string

Tags: pandas

I have the following df, and I would like to apply a filter over the column names and simply remain those that begin with a certain string:

This is my current df:

```
ruta2:
             Current SAN Prev.1m SAN Prev.2m SAN Prev.3m SAN Current TRE  \

A                   5           6           7           6           3
B                   6           5           7           6           6
C                  12          11          11          11           8
```

Basically what I would like is to filter the dataframe and remain the columns that begin with `Current`.

Then the desired output would be:

```
ruta2:
             Current SAN  Current TRE  

A                   5            3
B                   6            6
C                  12            8
```

In order to do this I tried this filter but outputs a value error :

```
ruta2=ruta2[~(ruta2.columns.str[:4].str.startswith('Prev'))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only need:

```
ruta2=ruta2.loc[:, ~(ruta2.columns.str[:4].str.startswith('Prev'))]
#same as
#ruta2=ruta2.loc[:, ~ruta2.columns.str.startswith('Prev')]
print (ruta2)
   Current SAN  Current TRE
A            5            3
B            6            6
C           12            8
```

Or:

```
cols = ruta2.columns[ ~(ruta2.columns.str[:4].str.startswith('Prev'))]
ruta2=ruta2[cols]
print (ruta2)
   Current SAN  Current TRE
A            5            3
B            6            6
C           12            8
```

But if need only `Current` columns use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) (`^` means start of string in regex):

```
ruta2=ruta2.filter(regex='^Current')
print (ruta2)
   Current SAN  Current TRE
A            5            3
B            6            6
C           12            8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#filter the columns names starting with 'Current'
ruta2[[e for e in ruta2.columns if e.startswith('Current')]]
Out[383]: 
   Current SAN  Current TRE
A           5           3
B           6           6
C          12           8
```

Or you can use a mask array to filter columns:

```
ruta2.loc[:,ruta2.columns.str.startswith('Current')]
Out[385]: 
   Current SAN  Current TRE
A           5           3
B           6           6
C          12           8
```